# Galois group as a subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over the field $F$, and let $G$ be the Galois group of $f$. Is it always the case that $G$ can be realized as a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$? If not, under what conditions would $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$?

This question came up because the text I'm using seems to use the fact that $G$ can be realized as a subgroup of $S_n$ in a few places, but I can't seem to find where in the text this result is actually proved. I am trying to answer this as follows: the elements of the Galois group induce permutations of the roots of $f$, so they act on the $n$ roots of $f$, which gives us a permutation representation $\rho: G \to S_n$. If $\rho$ is injective, then $G$ can be realized as a subgroup of $S_n$, but this doesn't seem to me to be a very useful criterion for determining when $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $\rho$ is always injective. The roots of $f$ generate its splitting field, so if an element of $G$ fixes them all then it acts trivially on the splitting field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ is the Galois group of the extension $E:F$ where $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$. Now, that means that $E=F(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$, where the $a_i$ are the roots of $F$. Now, you can directly prove that every element of the Galois group $G$ is determined by what it does on the roots, and that every root must be mapped to a root. So, there is an injective map $G\to S_{\{a_1,\cdots ,a_n\}}$. This functions is easily seen to be a homomorphism of groups, thus an embedding of the Galois group $G$. Now, identify the codomain group with $S_n$, and you obtain that the Galois group can be identified with a subgroup of $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

A condition to $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{S}_n$ is that $f$ be irreducible, so you can have an injective map from the roots of $f$ to $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and then $G$ can be seen as a subgroup of permutations acting on $\{1,2,...,n\}$

Comment: Why do you need the requirement that $f$ is irreducible?

Comment: Irreducible implies that $G$ is *transitive*.

Comment: If it is not irreducible, it has repeated roots, so $S_{\{a_1,...,a_n\}}$ will not be $\mathbb{S}_n$, will be $\mathbb{S}_k$ with $k\leq n$